# Detect and install correct graphics driver for RX 590

Tags: graphics, amdgpu

I'm running a new setup here, Ryzen 5 3600 with Sapphire Nitro+ Radeon RX 590.

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 (no flavour) with the NetInstall without any problems or hacks - I know this hardware is pretty new and most distros (including full Ubuntu iso currently) can't boot this hardware due to kernel panics and blackscreens.

Its running fine with Steam, but some nativ games like Deus Ex or Rise of the Tomb Raider randomly crash on benchmark, also give out warning about unsupported graphics. Other games like South Park (with proton) or Project Cars 2 run just fine.

Ubuntu Info tab says it's running RX 590 - Additional drivers tab is empty, nothing detected. All additional repos are activated.

lspci only shows VGA up to RX 580, nothing about RX 590.

Steams hardware info tells me

> ```
> driver: X.Org Radeon RX 590 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.27.0, 5.0.0-20-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
> ```

Shouldn't this be amdgpu or something like that?

Is there a safe way to tell which driver I'm running? 
If I'm not running the latest/best driver for my graphics card, how to install in a way that updates with apt?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have information regarding Open Source drivers, but, as regards AMD proprietary Drivers, I must tell you there is no yet any version for Ubuntu 19.04.
Check AMD website discussion: https://community.amd.com/thread/2381 . I am stuck at Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for precisely this reason.

Good luck!

Comment: Looks like you're right, right now there seems to be no amdgpu driver on Ubuntu 19.04, correct link is https://community.amd.com/thread/238156 .